# Python count number of element in the list but not in the right position without duplicates

Tags: python

I want the following :

```
In [1]: check('ABCD', 'ABCD')
Out[1]: (4, 0)

In [2]: check('AAAA', 'ABCD')
Out[2]: (1, 0)

In [3]: check('AADA', 'ABCD')
Out[3]: (1, 1)

In [4]: check('ADDA', 'ABCD')
Out[4]: (1, 1)

In [5]: check('ADDB', 'ABCD')
Out[5]: (1, 2)
```

The function check takes two arguments, the first being the guess, the second being the right code.
In "Out", the first number is number of right letters at the right place.
The second one is the number of right letters but not in the right place.
With my code, I can find with no problem de the first number but the second one is giving me an hard time as I can't come up with a code that doesn't count duplicate.
i.e: if I do `check('ADDB', 'ABCD')` I get `(1,4)` because it counts the one at the right place (should not), the two 'D' (should count as 1 ), and B (this one is ok).
Here the code :

```
def check(guess, code):
    cInCode = 0 # letter in code but wrong place
    cInPlace = 0 # right letter & right place
    for x in range(0, len(code)):
        if code[x]==guess[x]:
            cInPlace += 1
        cInCode += code.count(guess[x])
    return '('+str(cInPlace)+','+str(cInCode)+')'
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Said on the very beginning of my thread man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would likely be to first count all elements in common, which can be done with a `collections.Counter` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). If you then subtract the elements that *are* in the right place, you'll get the elements that are common but in the wrong place.

```
from collections import Counter

def common_elements(guess, code):
    # Counter() makes frequency counts
    # "&" intersects them (counting the elements in common)
    # .values() takes only the counts, and sum() adds them up
    return sum((Counter(guess) & Counter(code)).values())

def right_place(guess, code):
    # zip() iterates over pairs of elements
    # eg zip('ABC', 'DEF') yields ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'F')
    return sum(a == b for a,b in zip(guess, code)) # assumes same length!

def wrong_place(guess, code):
    return common_elements(guess, code) - right_place(guess, code)
```

Comment: my maaann thank you so much! Learnt so much from it

Answer (score 1):

Another answer shorter than main answer :

```
def check(code, guess):
    match = sum(1 for c, g in zip(code, guess) if c == g)
    common = sum((Counter(code) & Counter(guess)).values())
    return match, common - match
```